# How to update packages installed via Homebrew?

Tags: macos, applications, homebrew, software-update

I've installed packages in my macOS using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and installed GUI apps using [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask).

How could I update my extensions and packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have your packages and apps you just need to run these commands in your terminal:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew upgrade --cask && brew cleanup
```

Comment: It didn't upgrade karabiner-elements. Needed to run `brew upgrade --cask karabiner-elements`

Comment: Might be overkill but I use: `brew update; brew upgrade --cask --greedy ; brew upgrade $(brew outdated | awk '{ print $1 }') ; brew cleanup`

Answer (score 4):

If you're only trying to upgrade **one package**:

```
brew upgrade package_name
```

**All packages**

```
brew update && brew outdated && brew upgrade && brew cleanup
```

---

Note, I had to add my own answer for this since I got here looking for just one, and noticed the top answer had `brew upgrade --cask`, while I got the following from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389080/how-to-update-packages-installed-via-homebrew):

During 2020 the sub-commands of the `cask` command were gradually integrated into the core of Homebrew and were deprecated. The core commands now operate on both formulae and casks. To limit their scope to only formulae or casks add the `--formula` or `--cask` option to the command line.

The `cask` command has been completely removed from Homebrew in version 2.6.0, released in December 2020.

There is a unified flow now for both formulae and casks:

```
brew update
brew outdated
brew upgrade
```

The first command (`brew update`) gets from the Homebrew servers the information about the most recent versions of the available formulae and casks.

The second command (`brew outdated`) lists the outdated installed formulae and casks. Add `--formulae` or `--casks` to the command line to limit the command scope to formulae or casks. Add `--greedy` to the command line to include in its output the casks that are marked as "auto-updateable".
This command is not needed. It can be used to see what programs will be upgraded before doing the actual upgrade.

The third command (`brew upgrade`) upgrades the packages listed by brew outdated. It also supports the options listed above for brew outdated and operates accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

For updating casks specifically, I’d recommend `brew cu`. It can detect whether an app has auto-update or not, and you can prevent updating of certain apps.

YOU NEED TO INSTALL THE COMMAND.
Install with: `brew tap buo/cask-upgrade`

Comment: No such command on brew 4.0.4

Comment: Did you try installing it with the tap?