MacOS Sequoia with Apps on External Drive
I have a macbook pro m3 and i bought a SSD enclouse with a M.2 ssd. I was thinking if there is a way for the apps that work from the external drive to be updated the same as if they were in the actual OS Applications folder.
For example, Figma and Discord won't update if they were installed on the external drive.
Would a symlink from the M2 towards MacOS Application folder work?

Typically, if you're short of space and need to farm things out to an external drive, it's not the apps themselves that take significant space. Both of those apps are measured in Megabytes, from what I can see. It's usually app/user data that fills disks. (There are some notable exceptions, of course.)

Sequoia does have a new setting for apps on an external drive, though it applies only to App Store apps - https://www.simplymac.com/apps/mac-app-store-apps-on-external-drives I can't test any of this, no Sequoia Mac.

Not sure if that is the case benwiggy as some apps that i have, have around 5gbs. Intelijj Idea IDE is pretty big

Yes, there are notable exceptions, such as IDEs. But even so: I'd suggest that moving app/user data is easier and will bring larger savings.  My entire /Applications/ folder is c. 64Gb. /Library/Application Support/ is nearly 100Gb.

Is there a place where all the app data is stored or is it all scattered around?

Static application data is stored within the .app bundle. Runtime and additional data is typically stored in either /Library/Application Support/ or ~/Library/Application Support/. If the application is sandboxed, this supporting material is stored in ~/Library/Containers. This layout is not assured and may vary for non-idiomatic applications.

As @GrahamMiln says, but also many apps allow you to specify where data is stored and that can be on an external disk.


Would a symlink from the M2 towards MacOS Application folder work?

No.
Unfortunately, there is no perfect solution that will move the entire /Applications folder to an external drive. /Applications is an illusion on macOS – it is a combination of  multiple folders across multiple volumes.
As Tetsujin comments, Mac App Store applications can be moved to an external drive since macOS 15, aka Sequoia.
For third party software, whose software updating mechanisms do not work outside of /Applications, report a bug with the developer and then consider using an application management tool like brew.
Homebrew Casks
Given the built-in updaters of Figma and Discord do not work when then application is not in /Applications, consider using the Homebrew project to manage the applications.
brew install --cask figma
brew install --cask discord
brew install --cask android-studio
brew install --cask intellij-idea

Once installed, all the applications managed by brew can be automatically updated using the command:
brew update

And for casks…
brew upgrade --cask --greedy

See the StackOverflow question Changing homebrew-cask installation directories for altering where applications are stored.
Application Data
Static application data is stored within the .app bundle. Runtime and additional data is typically stored in either:

/Library/Application Support/
~/Library/Application Support/

If the application is sandboxed, this supporting material is stored in ~/Library/Containers.
This layout is not assured and may vary for non-idiomatic applications.
User Data
Applications and tools typically store their files within your home folder, ~/. Most allow you to select the destination.
For shoebox style applications, like Apple's Photos.app, check the settings of each application. Many will allow you to move the location of their files too.
Caches
To save more space on the internal drive, try a symlink for /Library/Caches and ~/Library/Caches to a folder on the external drive.

So you suggest installing apps with homebrew and change the location of them? What should i do with the apps that can't be installed with homebrew?

Android Studio, XCode for eg, but I was wondering. So if you say that I install the apps with homebrew cask on external drive it will then update the apps as they were like in the Applications folder on the Mac?

I have tried the homebrew --cask method. For example, for Discord, even though it has been installed with homebrew, when the app needs an update, it deletes itself which means i have to run the homebrew --cask command again. Is there a fix for that? I also tried having a symlink for the Application Support folder but that didn't help either as it re-created all the files

@EnCoder2000 please ask a new question about how to get brew to update casks. This will attract more attention than a comment. You may also want to log a bug with the Homebrew project about the cask not updating as expected.

Try brew upgrade --cask --greedy and see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389080/how-to-update-packages-installed-via-homebrew and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968664/upgrade-all-the-casks-installed-via-homebrew-cask
